# Recalling with Devise to different action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, warden

```
class Api::V1::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token,
                     :if => Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json'}

  respond_to :json

  def create
    warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")
    render :status => 200,
           :json => { :success => true,
                      :info => "Logged in",
                      :data => { :auth_token => current_user.authentication_token } }
  end

  def destroy
    warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")
    current_user.update_column(:authentication_token, nil)
    render :status => 200,
           :json => { :success => true,
                      :info => "Logged out",
                      :data => {} }
  end

  def failure
    render :status => 401,
           :json => { :success => false,
                      :info => "Login Failed",
                      :data  => {} }
  end

end
```

When I input the wrong email or password, I receive back the following json: `{error:"Invalid email or password"}`. This is great, and solves an initial issue I had, but when will the warden ever recall to `#failure`?

Comment: Are the users you are trying to login with unconfirmed? There is a known issue here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/675 where the recall option is not picked up

Comment: Users that login have been confirmed already.

Comment: Do you see the correct "Logged In" when you enter the right details?

Comment: Yeah, it works perfectly fine when the details are correct. In fact, I was surprised to find that when I entered the details wrong, that I immediately got `{error:"Invalid email or password"}`. This is convenient, but then it makes me question when I would ever get into the failure action.

Answer (score 0):

That is because Devise will always call its `FailureApp#http_auth` callback [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/failure_app.rb#L38) for *non-navigational* request format (like `json`).

I don't know how to fix that behaviour without implementing your own `FailureApp`. [This is an example](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated) from Devise Wiki which uses custom `FailureApp` but for slightly different problem.

PS. You may also consider using [Warden::Proxy#authenticate](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/hassox/warden/Warden%2FProxy%3Aauthenticate) method.